# Create a select option in the react js from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image][image]I am new to the react-redux. I actually know this question is a very basic question,

Here, I have an object which is like,

```
questionsCount : [ {
    Id : "CSS"
    count: "1",
    level:"Easy",
    type: Non_code},{
    Id : "CSS"
    count: "2",
    level:"Medium",
    type: code},
    {
    Id : "CSS"
    count: "5",
    level:"Tough",
    type: code},
    {
    Id : "java"
    count: "2",
    level:"Tough",
    type: Non-code},
    {
    Id : "Html"
    count: "4",
    level:"Easy",
    type: code},]
```

Now,I have one select drop-down where I want to create an options , So I tried

```
return this.state.questionsCount.map((item) =>
            <option key={item.Id}>{item.Id}</option>
        );

 In the props I get the level type.
```

Now, Here what its creating all the option elements with repetative Id's.

Now, What I want to do is that,

the option element will be like, first it should have only provided level elements meanes,

```
css code:0,Non_code:1
```

So,Currently Its getting duplicated .

Its getting duplicated because Id is getting repeated. Can any one help me with this ? Thanks

Here,I have that object. Now In that object there are multiple objects which has Id and count and level and type .

Now, from this objects I want to create the select options from this.

It has three diff levels.

expected Output would be like ,
   It will be having only easy level

```
<option>Css code:0,non_code-1></option>
<option>Html code:4,non_code-0></option>
```

for tough options,

```
<option>Css code:5,non_code-1></option>
<option>java code:0,non_code-2></option>
```

same for medium.and tough.

One technology can have code type or non code type questions of type easy or medium or tough. So, I want to create the drop-down of that technolgy depends upon the levels.

If code or non-code not present then it will have 0 for that.

Comment: Not able to understand what exactly you want to achieve. Could you show your expected result

Comment: okay will add that

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have just updated my code

Comment: One thing is that, In the props I get the props.type which will tell that currently what type we need to iterate. I mean Easy or tough or medium

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri did you get what I want to ask ?

Comment: where do you get the level information from. also what combination of keys will be unique for your data object

Comment: I am passing it as a props to the select component.And Combination is like Id, level, type this are the keys, Id can be same I mean css can have easy or medium or tough level with each can have code non code type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand in your case, you wish to create a select dropdown based on the difficulty level. To achieve that, you would need to filter our the question based on difficult first before rendering like

```
processQuestions(questionsCount, difficulty) {
  const res = questionsCount.filter(item => item.level === difficulty);
  return res.reduce((acc, item) => {
     if (acc[item.Id]) {
        acc[item.Id] = { ...acc[item.Id], [item.type]: acc[item.Id][item.type]? acc[item.Id][item.type] + 1 : 1};
     } else {
        acc[item.Id] = { [item.type]: 1};
     }
     return acc;
  }, {})
}
render() {
   const { difficulty } = this.props;
   const questionsData = this.processQuestions(this.state.questionCount, difficulty);
   return Object.entries(questionsData).map(([questionId, data]) => {
        return (
           <option key={questionId}>{questionId} code: {data.code} non_code: {data['Non-code']}</option>
        ) 
   })
}
```

Comment: @shubhamKhatri thanks for your solution. Worked perfectly